# Making a dynamic path string for saving an image

Tags: c#, dynamic, path, printscreen

First time posting on this forum, and also very new to coding. Sorry if this is an easy question but I'm doing all sorts of things wrong.

**The situation**
I want to save a screenshot, and I want to filename to be the current date like:

```
string path = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();
```

And I'm trying this:

```
ScreenCapture s = new ScreenCapture();
s.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,(@"C:\images\" + path + ".png"), ImageFormat.Png);
```

which is a mess, and doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated even if you tell me to first learn more and then start with my own projects.

**EDIT:**
The screencapture class I used: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please. What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have invalid characters in your time string.
Use:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss");
```

You can change the order as you like. The order I wrote is "day, month, year, hour, minute, second"

Comment: I got this for a filename: 030812000013
It is a start! that's probably the order I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

you could declare your variable using the examples below

```
var path = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss");
```

or

```
 string path = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss");
```

Comment: Yeah, got it working many thanks. is there a way to close this thread?

Comment: why would you want to close the thread.. it's best to keep a working solution open in the case that a junior developer may run into the same issue..

Comment: Oke, I will keep it this way.

Comment: But you should mark the answer that you think is the best as an answer to your question.